# How do I dispatch key events to the correct JavaFX shape that was under the mouse?

Tags: javafx

I have a JavaFX `Scene` with a couple of different `Group`s.  Each group has several filled `PolyLine`s.

I would like to trigger some computation when the user presses the <kbd>n</kbd> key while they are inside one of the filled `PolyLine`s.

I used `scene.setOnKeyPressed` to install a `KeyEvent` handler and printed it out.  I'm not sure how to figure out which `PolyLine` the event occurred over.  The `target` of the event happens to be a `Button` left over from an early tutorial I was following.  The event printout does not display any coordinates, and even if it had some, I'm not sure how best to traverse the `Node` tree to hunt down which `PolyLine` is of interest.

What is the proper idiom for responding to key events that happen while the mouse is over a JavaFX `Shape`?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by _while they are inside of one of the filled polyLines_?

Comment: I should have said "while the mouse is inside one of the filled PolyLines".

Comment: indeed ... always good to be precise when asking <g>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Key events are only delivered to the `Node` that has the focus. You can request a `Node` obtain focus by calling `Node#requestFocus()`. Using that, one solution is you can add mouse event handlers to each `Shape` that request focus when the mouse enters the area. Then you add key event handlers to each `Shape` rather than the `Scene`. The key event will be delivered to, and handled by, the `Node` with the focus, which will be the `Shape` which has the mouse over it. To stop key events from being delivered to the `Shape` once the mouse exits the area you can add a handler that requests focus somewhere else (e.g. a common parent or the root of the scene).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public final class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        var root = new HBox(15, createCircle(), createTriangle(), createSquare());
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(30));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Shapes");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Shape createCircle() {
        var circle = new Circle(100);
        addHandlers(circle, "Circle");
        return circle;
    }

    private Shape createTriangle() {
        var polygon = new Polygon(100, 0, 200, 200, 0, 200, 100, 0);
        addHandlers(polygon, "Triangle");
        return polygon;
    }

    private Shape createSquare() {
        var rectangle = new Rectangle(200, 200);
        addHandlers(rectangle, "Square");
        return rectangle;
    }

    private void addHandlers(Shape shape, String name) {
        // Notice you have access to the specific shape in the 
        // event handlers. The source of the event will also
        // be the shape.
        shape.setOnMouseEntered(event -> {
            if (!shape.isFocused()) {
                event.consume();
                shape.requestFocus();
            }
        });
        shape.setOnMouseExited(event -> {
            if (shape.isFocused()) {
                event.consume();
                shape.getScene().getRoot().requestFocus();
            }
        });
        shape.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.N) {
                event.consume();
                System.out.println("KEY_PRESSED['N']: " + name);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Another option to adding `MOUSE_ENTERED` and `MOUSE_EXITED` event handlers is to listen to the `Node#hover` property of the `Shape`. When it changes to `true`, request the focus; when it changes to `false`, remove the focus.

---

Requesting the `Shape` have the focus will pull the focus away from the `Node` that currently has the focus. For instance, if you have a `TextField` with the focus then it will lose the focus whenever the mouse hovers over one of the `Shape`s. This will prevent the user from being able to type into the `TextField` (until they go and click on it).

If this behavior is undesirable then you can, instead of requesting focus, maintain some field/property/model that tells you which `Shape` is currently hovered over. Then you'd add an event **filter** to a common parent of the `TextField` and `Shape`s. If a `Shape` has the mouse hovering over it you do what is necessary and then consume the event (which will stop it from reaching whichever `Node` has the focus).